# Are there any use cases where merging the namespace in containers can be useful

Tags: cloud, containers, virtualization, lxc

Containers use the namespace isolation feature. It offers a lot of advantages like security,etc. Different namespaces in linux can be Network, Pid, Ipc, Mount,etc.

I have to implement a feature for LXC containers where any particular namespace can be merged.For eg. instead of keeping network namespace isolated for every container,i can share it. **My question is "are there any specific advantages of this approach"**.

*Why would i merge the namespaces in a container when the inherent feature of the container is namespace isolation.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the debugging and testing purposes but at the cost of security.